# Are there any numerically-plausible perfect binary code parameters besides (90,2)?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, binomial-coefficients, coding-theory

In order for a perfect binary code on $n$ symbols to correct $k$ errors, we need the sum

$${n\choose 0}+{n\choose 1}+\ldots+{n\choose k}$$

to be a power of two, since the number of codewords is $2^n$ divided by that sum. If one looks in Pascal's triangle for such sums, one finds:

- $k=n$, corresponding to a code with a single keyword (trivial)
- $k=0$, corresponding to a code with all $2^n$ codewords that corrects no errors (trivial)
- $k=\lfloor \frac n2\rfloor$ when $n$ is odd, corresponding to two codewords (trivial)
- $n=2^m-1, k=1$, corresponding to a Hamming code
- $n=23, k=3$, corresponding to the perfect Golay code.

All of the above correspond to real error-correcting codes, and in fact the above is a complete list of perfect binary codes (see e.g. the assertion in section 2 [here](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82300241.pdf)). But there are numerical coincidences in Pascal's triangle that don't lead to a perfect binary code, such as the fact that

$${90\choose 0}+{90\choose 1}+{90\choose 2} = 4096 = 2^{12}$$

I'm curious whether there are any *other* such numerical coincidences in Pascal's triangle. It seems that there aren't - I've checked the first 1,000,000 rows - but I don't know how I'd prove this.

Comment: Interestingly, $ 90^2+90+1 = 8191 = 4096*2-1 $, but I don't know if this just a coincidence or not ...

Comment: @Aurel-BG It's basically a coincidence, applicable other values as well. Note for any integer $x$ that $1 + x + \frac{x(x-1)}{2} = y \;\to\; 2(1 + x) + x(x - 1) = 2y$. This further leads to $1 + 2x + (x^2 - x) = 2y - 1 \;\to\; x^2 + x + 1 = 2y - 1$.

Comment: You could use Heuristic methods - $x$ is a power of 2 with probability around $1/x$. If you restrict to $k=1$, the sum of $1/S(n,1)$ increases log(N) as expected, but the sum of reciprocals $k=2$ is finite, and I suspect the sum of $1/S(n,k)$ $n-1>k>1$ is also finite which would suggest (ignoring the obvious cases like the ones you mentioned) that there’s only a finite number of numerical coincidences.

Comment: @RavenclawPrefect, $k=2: 1+n+\frac{n(n-1)}{2} = 2^x$.
We can take the three cases $x=3m,x=3m+1$, and $x=3m+2$.
It can be reduced the problem to finding the integer points on elliptic curves  $Y^2 = X^3-7, Y^2 = X^3-28$, and $Y^2 = X^3-112$.
Magma says that all integral points are $(n,x)=(90,12),(5,4)$.

Comment: Looking for such rare anomalies in general beyond the first few values of $k$ is probably hopeless but very likely incredibly difficult to rule out. Why should people be interested in this question, after all it is known that no more perfect codes exist.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some comments and ideas, a proof for $k=3$, and no new solutions. Beware of misprints and mistakes.

First. let us define the polynomial $F_k(x)$ by
$$
\frac{F_k(x)}{k!}=\binom{x}{0}+\cdots+\binom{x}{k}
$$
which has degree $k$, and integer coefficients with leading coefficient 1.
In particular, $F_0(x)=1$, $F_1(x)=x+1$, $F_2(x)=x^2+x+2$, and so on.

The question then becomes finding $n,k,m$ for which $F_k(n)=k!\cdot 2^m$.

Cases $k=0,1$ have already been addressed, so I'll skip those. I'll also skip cases with $n\le k$ which solve for $m=n$. So what remains is $n>k\ge2$.

We may also note that for $k$ odd, $F_k(x)$ will always be a multiple of $x+1$ since we can write
$$
\frac{F_k(x)}{k!}
=\binom{x}{0}+\cdots+\binom{x}{k}
=\binom{x+1}{1}+\binom{x+1}{3}+\cdots+\binom{x+1}{k}
$$
where all binomials on the right have $x+1$ as a factor.

Note that I'll use $x$ instead of $n$ when treating $F_k(x)$ as a polynomial in $x$ rather than then integer value $F_k(n)$ for some particular integer $n$. So when I write that $x+1$ is a factor of $F_k(x)$ for odd $k$, this is as polynomials.

#### Case $k=3$:

I'll do this first since it is the easier case. Adding up the binomial terms, we get $F_3(x)=x^3+5x+6=(x+1)(x^2-x+6)$. We wish to find all $n,m$ for which $F_3(n)=3!\cdot 2^m=3\cdot 2^{m+1}$. This results in two alternatives:
$$
\text{a)}\quad x+1=2^p\quad\text{and}\quad x^2-x+6=3\cdot2^q,\\
\text{b)}\quad x+1=3\cdot 2^p\quad\text{and}\quad x^2-x+6=2^q\\
$$
where $p,q$ are both non-negative integers, $p+q=m+1$. Plugging $x=2^p-1$ or $x=3\cdot2^p-1$ into $x^2-x+6$ on the right hand side, we see that it suffices to check for small $p,q$. Eg, if $x=2^p-1$, we get $x^2-x+6=2^{2p}-3\cdot2^p+8=3\cdot2^q$, so we cannot have both $p,q>3$.

Checking for small values of $p,q$, the only solutions with $n>k=3$ are $(n,m)=(7,6),(23,11)$.

#### Odd $k$

For odd $k$, we can factor $F_k(x)=(x+1)\cdot G_k(x)$. Solving $F_k(n)=k!\cdot2^m$ means we can write $n+1=a\cdot2^p$, $G_k(n)=b\cdot2^q$ where $k=a\cdot b\cdot 2^r$ with odd $a,b$ and $p+q=r+m$. This results in more cases than for $k=3$, but for each $k$ I suspect it should still be a finite problem.

#### Case $k=2$:

For $k=2$ we want to solve $F_2(n)=n^2+n+2=2^{m+1}$.

Rewrite this as $(2n+1)^2=4n^2+4n+1=2^{m+3}-7$. Looking at this modulo powers of 2 reduces the options for $n$, but it seems $-7$ remains a square for all powers.

If $m=2r-1$ is odd, we can factor $2^{2r}-(2n+1)^2=7$, into $(2^r+2n+1)(2^r-2n-1)=7\cdot 1$, which gives us $(n,m)=(1,1)$ as the only solution, which has already been addressed as $n\le k$.

So we must have $m$ even.

##### Alternative approach

This was what I tried first, which might interest some.

For $k=2$ we have $F_2(x)=x^2+x+2$. This does not factor like for odd $k$.

However, if we introduce $\omega=(1+\sqrt{7}i)/2$, we can factor it $F_2(x)=(x+\omega)(x+\bar\omega)=(x+\omega)(x+1-\omega)$ where the complex conjugate $\bar\omega=1-\omega$.

The ring $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$ of numbers $u+v\omega$ is a principle ideal domain, hence has unique factorization. The number 2 factors $2=\omega\bar\omega=\omega(1-\omega)$, so the equation becomes
$$
F_2(n)=(n+\omega)(n+1-\omega)=2^m=\omega^m(1-\omega)^m
$$
which means we are looking for powers $\omega^m=\pm(s+\omega)$ where $s$ is either $n$ or $-(n+1)$.

A search for $m$ up to $100000$ yielded $(n,m)=(5,4),(90,12)$.
Not sure if this approach can be used to obtain a full solution.